# Javascript/jQuery - parse hashtags in a string using regex, except for anchors in URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing

I've looked at a couple of other possible solutions on SO but didn't see any that were doing what I was doing.

Currently I have been able to parse a string and detect hash tags with the following code:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig, "$1<span class='hash_tag'>$2</span>").replace(/\s*$/, "");
```

And this successfully detects all sorts of #hashtags.  However it also detects anchors in URLs, such as: http://www.example.com/#anchor - I can't work out how to modify what I have to exclude anchors while keeping it flexible.

Thanks

Comment: well, you are going deep into something nasty. HTML parsing!
BTW, where do the hashtags in URLs located? are they in <a> ?or might be in anywhere?

Comment: hi @MohammedJoraid - the URL would be mentioned in a string, like http://example.com/#anchor and not within an <a> tag. I think the best thing would be preceding the hashtag must be a space/newline character (or start of string) - anything else and it isn't considered a hash tag.

Comment: #hola#yes#livelong  



..
 opps, i forgot to add space before using the #

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a regex to match hashtag(#) if it has a space before it or it's beginning of string..  like so:

```
(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/pJ4wC5

Javascript:

```
var string = '#hello This is an #example of some text with #hash-tags - http://www.example.com/#anchor but dont want the link';

string = string.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<span class='hash_tag'>$2</span>");

console.log(string);
```

Output:

```
<span class='hash_tag'>#hello</span> This is an <span class='hash_tag'>#example</span> of some text with <span class='hash_tag'>#hash-tags</span> - http://www.example.com/#anchor but dont want the link
```

Comment: Thanks @MElliott - I modified it to (^|\s)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*) and that seems to be perfect. Allowing _ - etc as part of the hashtag.

Comment: btw, thanks for showing me regex101 - great site to test the regex on.  Also a small modification to yours allowed the _ as part of the tag too: (^|\s)(#[a-z\d-_]+)

Comment: @Martin, Awesome!  Glad I could help.  Thank you.  Yes, regex101 has become my favorite. :)

Comment: Any idea how I could get the hashtag value out of this without the proceeding # 

i.e. $2 == example rather than $2 == #example

Comment: @RossJ, Yes, in the regex you could just exclude the '#' from the capture group (parens), like so: /(^|\s)#([a-z\d-]+)/ig

Comment: Hi guys, you need to change this snippet: string.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<span class='hash_tag'>$2</span>"); to string = string.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<span class='hash_tag'>$2</span>");

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but if you need styling, here's a solution i used on a project:

```
<div id='result'>The quick brown #fox jumps over the #second  lazy dog</div>
<div id='result2'> </div>

//jquery
var str = $('#result').html(); 
var edt = str.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<span class='hash_tag'>$2</span>");

$('#result2').html(edt);




//CSS
.hash_tag {color:red;}
#result {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to try to match the "a" tag first and after trying the hashtag subpattern that is in a capturing group. A callback function tests the capturing group and returns the "a" tag or the modifier hashtag substring:

```
var str = '<a href="sdfsdfd#ank"> qsdqd</a> #toto (#titi) ^#t-_-Ata';

var result = str.replace(/<a\b[^>]*>|\B(#[^\W_][\w-]*)/gi,
                         function (m, p) {
                          return (p) ? '<span class="hash_tag">'+m+'</span>' : m;
                         });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Casimer - thanks, however the URL would be mentioned in a string, like http://example.com/#anchor and not within an <a> tag. I think the best thing would be preceding  the #hashtag must be a space/newline character  (or start of string) - anything else and it isn't considered a hash tag.