# Specific CSS colors for the text

Tags: regex, html, css

I want to use different font settings if the text starts with # (hash). I want the normal text color to be black but blue color for the hashtag. Is it possible using css?? i can do it from javascript but i cant use any scripting. I need to do it using Css. Is it possible?

```
<div id='container' class='container'>
    This is a sample text #text#sample
</div>
```

In the example above. `This is a sample text` is black in color while `#text#sample` should be blue.

Is there any way i can use regex or any other alternative? Thanks in advance

Comment: _CSS_ is used to style _Elements_ (or _pseudo-Elements_). The text needs to be in it's own _Element_ to be selectable by _CSS_.

Comment: Wrap it around a span?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript/jQuery - parse hashtags in a string using regex, except for anchors in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421526/javascript-jquery-parse-hashtags-in-a-string-using-regex-except-for-anchors-i)

Comment: i dont want to use Javascript.@stdob--

Comment: The text i am getting is dynamic

Comment: Short answer, No, this isn't possible without JS

Comment: Use JS to grab the text and style it. Not possible with CSS.

Comment: so not possible through JS. The data is coming using a JSON feed and dynamically creating html divs to set the text. I am not able to read the json call so thats why i thought to define CSS rule to make it simple but thats not a case now. Thanks everyone

Answer (score -2):

use the span attribute in HTML and place the span brackets around the text and give the span an ID. Like so:

```
black <span id="span">blue</span> black
```

Then use CSS with the ID you assigned and everything between the span brackets will be effected

Comment: why did this get marked down? I've done this many times on my own code and it works fine.

Comment: chris i think you didnt get my question. I just want to make hastags blue in color

Comment: he said the text was dynamic, he can't add a span around it

Comment: well then use the span tag on just the hashtags themselves. It'll work the same.