# extract hashtag and mention from instagram

Tags: java, instagram, hashtag, mention

is there any java library or regex pattern for extracting hashtag and user mention from instagram media caption? I know twitter-text api but it can not handle for no space hashtag.

Comment: You should start from here `https://www.instagram.com/developer`. If it is still not working post your code which demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work `(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)` (got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421526/javascript-jquery-parse-hashtags-in-a-string-using-regex-except-for-anchors-i))

Anyway, if you are using the Instagram API, there is a part of the result when you call it that gives you all the hashtags:

```
  ["data"]=>
  array(14) {
    ["attribution"]=>
    NULL
    ["tags"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "workingermany"
      [1]=>
      string(18) "trabajarenalemania"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "radeberger"
    }
```

If, as requested in your comment, you need Korean chars, just add them to the regular expression like this: `(^|\s)(#[a-z\p{Hangul}\d-]+)`
The more alphabets you want, the more set of chars you should add, like `\p{Hiragana}`, `\p{Katakana}`, or `\p{Latin}`

Comment: it can not handle for no space hashtag and korean, chinese, japanese ..language. like "#hello#world #안녕하세요 "